How to concat columns of multiple rows and return only one row?
I have two tables which I am inner joining
The result now has multiple rows because one column in Table 2 has different values.
I want to concat the column for each row and return only 1 row with the concatenated values in one column.
SELECT
    Table1.ID, CONCAT(Table2.Col , ' , ', Table3.Col ) 
FROM
    Table1
INNER JOIN
    Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
INNER JOIN
    Table3 ON Table2.ID = Table3.ID
           AND Table2.Col != Table3.Col

The problems with this is that it will only concat 2 rows and not include if there are more rows.
I don't believe I can use Pivot because I can not hardcode the values to pivot.

Sounds like you're after STRING_AGG (or a similar function if you don't use MSSQL), but hard to tell. Your question is too vague. Please provide a minimal reproducible example and tag your RDBMS.

Azure Data Studio is an IDE; it doesn't tell us what database engine you are using. Tagging ADS for your RDBMS is like tagging Visual Studio for your programming language.

And please include some sample data/desired result.

It is not officially supported but there is a way to do that, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv/19584555#19584555

That's a documented anti pattern, @endo64 , that method should not be used.

STRING_AGG is what I was looking for. Thank you @Jonas Metzle and everyone else.

this is not an answer more like a comment

Please remove this, as this is not an answer rather a comment

STRING_AGG is literally the answer, as stated in the answer.
